# Multiple authentication methods for a user in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I would like to let my users have a choice which authentication method to use. For example, they could be presented with a menu to pick an option (username/pass, username/pass+OTP, etc).
Then, Keycloak should, based on their choice, assign specific scope to the token.

Is this possible to do with Keycloak (probably by somehow utilizing auth methods chaining) and how? I couldn’t find this in the documentation but it seems as a reasonable use-case to me.

Comment: I guess *I'm* not sure if I can understand the use case.  If, for example, you've done the work of implementing an OTP, why would you allow an end user to **downgrade** security?  In general I feel that it's the server side that sets the level of security.  An end user will always do what's easiest, not necessarily what is most secure.

Comment: Any news? I would like to implement the same scenario as Mike described... @stdunbar imagine that you have two different two factor authentication methods and want to let the user decide what method he wants to use it...

Comment: @Winter I found a solution. It requires some implementation and I will provide details very soon, I'm very busy at the moment.

Comment: Tks @mike ! i will wait for your solution :D

Comment: @Winter I've answered :)

Comment: tks it was really a help ! :D It s a bit sad that we need to "duplicate" code and create a custom for methods that already exist in keycloak.

Comment: I agree. But this is really a strange use case, you have to admit, that they didn't predict :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my solution:

[image]

Circled authenticators are custom ones for which I provided a custom implementation.
I used the fall-through mechanism, which means I that first authenticator implements a custom form: [image]

which lets the user choose authenticator and captures user's choice in a variable.
Later, this variable is used in the following authenticators to decide whether to do the authentication or to pass on control to the next authenticator.

You can read more about Authentication SPI in the following page: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi

And [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/authenticator) you can see how to implement custom authenticator.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your solution. It's clear, but I'm not sure that it's very secure, nor if it will resist upgrade of the Keyclooak version. Either way good job here 

Comment: That last screen is shown while logged out?

Answer (score 9):

Here is what i did and it works,

'My goal was give ability to client to choose authentication flow, choose between otp based email and sms.'

I created a new authentication flow, see screenshot :

[image]

select '**Alternative**' on both flows.

On login form new link will appear '*try another way*'

[image]

Now the client can choose between flows. see screenshot :

[image]

Comment: This should be the correct answer. There is no need to use a manual fall-through mechanism as shown in the selected answer. Keycloak now provides this out of the box if you have multiple alternative methods allowed.

Comment: How did you create the last screen?

Comment: when you configure two alternative flows, the last screen automatically created by keycloak to give you the ability to select which flow u want. it's is different to default screen because i used costumized theme (i made some changes on page)

Comment: @Chawki how did you change the options' names in the last screen? Because even changing the subflow name and description those options don't update.

Comment: @remarcoble if i have a good memory, i remember that i changed them on some config or html file (i can not remember exactly where), to do that you can do a quick string search to find in which file it exist (search by option name shown in your screen e.g: grep -r "option_name" ./keycloak_folder).

Comment: I'm trying to store the most recently used Authentication method. What I have now is that users are always presented the same option (even if this is not the first flow that is configured)